# Loop through folder changing file extensions VBA

Tags: vba, excel

On a monthly basis I have to aggregate daily files.  The issue is I need the files to be in "TXT", but they are sent to me as "WRI".

I am able to do one file at a time if it is hardcoded with the following.

```
Name "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1\SQLEXEC.WRI" As "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1\SQLEXEC.TXT"
```

However, I want to be able to loop through the folder. But I am not sure how to change the code to allow it to loop.

```
Sub ConvertToTXT()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim strPath As String 
Dim strFile As String

strPath = "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1\" strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.wri")

Do While strFile <> ""

Name "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1\SQLEXEC.WRI" As "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1\SQLEXEC.TXT"

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you need to look into how `Dir` works. See [VBA topics](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/topics) on Documentation.SO. Also your loop body should use `strFile` for the old name, and you need logic that removes/replaces the extension in the new name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` for this - it's much less prone to errors than manually building filepath strings.  You'll need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime:

```
Private Sub ConvertToTXT(filePath As String)
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim directory As Folder
        Set directory = .GetFolder(filePath)
        Dim target As File
        For Each target In directory.Files
            If LCase$(.GetExtensionName(target.Name)) = "wri" Then
                Dim newName As String
                newName = .BuildPath(filePath, .GetBaseName(target.Name)) & ".txt"
                .MoveFile target.Path, newName
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Call it by passing it the directory you want to perform the renaming in:

```
ConvertToTXT "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1"
```

Note that is doesn't care if there's a trailing `\` or not - this also works:

```
ConvertToTXT "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1\"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ConvertToTXT()

    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Folder1"
    Dim strFile As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\" & "*.wri")

    Do While strFile <> ""
        Name strPath & "\" & strFile As strPath & "\" & Replace(strFile, ".wri", ".txt")
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I tried using this but unfortunately, when it runs, I'm not sure it is doing anything. It runs and I receive no errors, but the files do not change from WRI to TXT.

Comment: @Comintern run with F8 to see the variables especially see if strFile is loaded with the names in the folder or not. I tested on my computer with different extensions and it works for sure. Double check your folder address and also whether you have any file which is wri. Check strFile when the line is executing (yellow), hover on it to show its value. It should pick the name of wri files